# What is the difference between tottime and cumtime on cProfile output?

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I am profiling a python script `main.py` using cProfile with the following command:

```
python -m cProfile -s tottime main.py
```

The output I get is (only copy-pasted the top lines of the output):

```
10184337 function calls (10181667 primitive calls) in 13.597 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    4.674    4.674   13.598   13.598 main.py:2(<module>)
 2142    2.964    0.001    4.663    0.002 load_aerdat3.py:61(getPacket)
  459    2.381    0.005    2.381    0.005 {waitKey}
1667989    1.170    0.000    1.170    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}

...
```

How can the `tottime` (4.674) be different from the `cumtime` (13.598) for `main.py`, since this function (ie. the whole script) is only called once?

Answer (score 148):

`tottime` is the total time spent *in the function alone*. `cumtime` is the total time spent in the function *plus* all functions that this function called.

The two values is going to be the same if a function never calls anything else. For example, `{waitKey}` doesn't appear to invoke anything else:

```
  459    2.381    0.005    2.381    0.005 {waitKey}
```

but `getPacket()` calls other functions, so it's `cumtime` column includes the time for those calls:

```
 2142    2.964    0.001    4.663    0.002 load_aerdat3.py:61(getPacket)
```

The `main.py` line covers all code run outside of functions, the global code; just the statements at that level took 4.674 seconds to run, but because those statements called other functions, the total cumulative time of the `main.py` code *plus all function calls made* is 13.598 seconds.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual):

> *tottime*
>   for the total time spent in the given function (and excluding time made in calls to sub-functions)
>
> [...]
>
> *cumtime*
>   is the cumulative time spent in this and all subfunctions (from invocation till exit). This figure is accurate even for recursive functions.

Comment: great, now I understand! somehow I missed that `tottime` does not include the subfunctions.. Thank you!

Comment: What does count as a subfunction and what does not? If I take a slice of a string for example, does it count as a call to a subfunction? Or does it count as a built-in, elementary operation inside the main function?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: Anything that is implemented in Python code, so can be instrumented. String slicing can't be instrumented because it is implemented in native machine code, compiled from C.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, now I understand why the profile module returns such results.