# How to determine what is causing a library to import slowly?

Tags: python

When I import Pandas or Numpy it's imported instantly, but when I import the library found here

https://github.com/ContextLab/supereeg

It takes a long time to import.  I'm updating my own forked copy and would like to reduce the amount of time it takes to load.  How do I go about diagnosing why it's taking so long?

Comment: I would start by figuring out how long it takes to import each of the modules found in `supereeg/__init__.py` (https://github.com/ContextLab/supereeg/blob/master/supereeg/__init__.py) since that is what's called when you do `import supereeg`. However, at a quick glace, I see that some modules here (like `model.py` call `from .brain import Brain` which might trick you into thinking `model.py` is the problem so you'll have to careful

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554374/python-profiling-imports-and-specially-init-is-what-seems-to-take-the-mos/50554426#50554426. Maybe the hints there get you started.

Comment: How long is long? milliseconds / seconds / minutes? You could start by printing something between every import in the `__init__.py` to get a rough indication of how time is spent.

Answer (score 2):

It probably does expensive initialization on import, which may be considered bad form. Either way, you can find out using Python's built-in profiler:

```
import cProfiler
cProfiler.run('import supereeg')
```

The output is not the easiest to parse at all times, but will give you an idea of what's happening. For more info on how to store/sort etc the reports, check the fine docs at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html