# How come the tottime is *greater* than cumtime, when using cProfile?

Tags: numpy, profiling, cprofile

I'm using cprofile and snakeviz to analyze some python code.
I'm getting weird results like this:
[image: profiling results]

Two questions:

1. Given that the `cumtime` is supposed to include the runtime of the routine and all subroutines, and the `tottime` is only the runtime of the routine itself - we would expect that the `cumtime` will always be greater (and this is indeed the most common thing) - why is it different here? Is it related to the fact I'm heavily relying on `numpy`?
2. what does the fractional `ncalls` mean? does it explain the odd `cumtime` vs. `tottime` behavior?

EDIT:
According to the [snakeviz documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmJdB.png), when there are two numbers in the `ncalls` column that means the call is recursive. So perhaps the tottime includes only the time spent in the function not including calls to itself recursively, and the cumtime only consider primitive calls. But this is only a guess, will appreciate if someone can make a more definitive statement.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404007/what-is-the-difference-between-tottime-and-cumtime-on-cprofile-output

Comment: @imM4TT there are many places that discuss how the cumtime can be more than the tottime. Here the question is how can the opposite happen, and I haven't seen this discussed anywhere.